# Solving a system of linear ODEs to show that the steps of a Poisson process are Poisson distributed

Tags: probability, ordinary-differential-equations, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

I'm trying to prove that for a Poisson process $N_t$ ,$ \ N_t \sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda t) $ for $t\geq 0$. I've got to the point where I have found the differential equation $p_{n}^\prime(t) = -\lambda p_n(t) + \lambda p_{n-1}(t) $ where $p_n(t) = P(N_t = n) $.

How can I solve this equation and show that $p_n(t) = \frac{e^{-\lambda t} (\lambda t)^n}{n!} $ and thus that $N_t$ is Poisson distributed?

Here's my working so far:

$$ \begin{align*} p_n(t+h) & = P(N_{t+h} = n) \\ & = P(N_{t+h} = n| N_t > n) P(N_t > n) + P(N_{t+h} = n | N_t = n)P(N_t = n)\\ &+ P(N_{t+h} = n | N_t = n-1) P(N_t = n-1) + P(N_{t+h} = n |N_t < n-1)P(N_t < n-1) \\ &= (1-\lambda h + o(h))p_{n}(t) + (\lambda h + o(h))p_{n-1}(t) + o(h) \end{align*} \implies \frac{p_{n}(t+h) - p_n(t)}{h} = -\lambda p_n(t) + \lambda p_{n-1}(t) + \frac{o(h)}{h}$$ Taking $h \rightarrow 0 $ we get $p_{n}^\prime(t) = -\lambda p_n(t) + \lambda p_{n-1}(t) $.

Comment: First, $p'_0(t)=-\lambda p_0(t)$ (not what you wrote) and $p_0(0)=1$ hence $p_0(t)=e^{-\lambda t}$. Next, define $q_n(t)=p_n(t)e^{\lambda t}$ and note that $p'_{n+1}(t)=-\lambda p_{n+1}(t)+\lambda p_n(t)$ (not what you wrote) translates as $q'_{n+1}(t)=\lambda q_n(t)$ hence $q_0(t)=1$ and, using the initial conditions $q_n(0)=0$ for every $n\geqslant1$, an easy recursion yields $q_n(t)=\frac{(\lambda t)^n}{n!}$ for every $n\geqslant0$, as desired.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that my workings would lead to $p_{n+1}^\prime (t) = -\lambda p_{n+1}(t) + \lambda p_n(t)$ if I simply replaced n by n+1, n-1 by n etc. ? Also can you explain how you used recursion from $q_{n+1}^\prime (t) = \lambda q_n $ to give the final result?

Comment: You first: $q_0(t)=1$ and $q'_1(t)=\lambda q_0(t)$, hence $q_1(t)=$ $____$. Now, $q_1(t)=$ $____$ and $q'_2(t)=\lambda q_1(t)$, hence $q_2(t)=$ $____$. And so on.

Comment: Ah ok, that's great - thanks very much for your help.